# Leibniz integral rule for differentiation under the integral sign - is this condition needed?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

See the general rule (the theorem) here:

[Leibniz rule - general form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

My question is: do we need to require the derivatives $a'(x)$ and $b'(x)$ to be continuous?

The Wikipedia page requires that condition.

But I have a calculus book which requires only that these derivatives exist i.e. it requires only that the functions $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are differentiable.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which conclusion you want to obtain. Let me discuss this on a simplified version of the general theorem for which you give a link.

Let $f \in C^0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ and $a,b \in C^0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$. Let us define $G \in C^0(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ by
$$
G(x) := \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \mathrm{d} t.
$$

- If you assume that $a$ and $b$ are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, then $G$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ also, but its derivative $G'$ is not guaranteed to be continuous.
- If you assume that $a,b \in C^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. that $a'$ and $b'$ both exist and are continuous), then $G \in C^1(\mathbb{R};\mathbb{R})$ (i.e. $G'$ exists and is continuous).

Comment: I see, thanks. That's interesting. The conclusion (in my book and also in Wikipedia btw) does not state that $G'$ is continuous. So I guess I was talking about the first option of the two options you stated.

Answer (score 1):

The formula is an application of the chain rule. Let $$H(u,v,x)=\int_u^0f(x,t)\,dt+\int_0^vf(x,t)\,dt$$ We want to find $${d\over dx}H(a(x),b(x),x)$$ So the assumptions needed for the chain rule should be satisfied. In particular it suffices that $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ are differentiable.